# JSON.Вложенные страницы

Tags: java, android, json

Есть такой JSON
http://app.wheelshop.com.ua/wheels?auto=4

Для наглядности прикреплю скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть в таком случае,если в нём вложены еще 2 страницы и их нужно приплюсовать одну к другой, в какую сторону думать?Нужно написать какой-то итератор?

Comment: В чём заключается конкретный вопрос, задача, проблема?

Comment: В том что я не знаю как добраться до полной информации, чтобы начать её парсить, а лишь к первому куску по url. Сейчас нужно узнать, что делают в таком случае профи, а то я не знаю в какую сторону даже думать.

Comment: Загружаете первую, берете из нее следующий URL и так по кругу, пока  next_page_url не будет пустым. Либо спросите у владельцев API, как забрать сразу все

Comment: Ну так и делайте парсинг по страницам. Закончили первую, загружайте вторую и парсите её. Закончили, переходите к третьей... Вам действительно нужны все страницы в одном месте? Пагинация ведь не спроста делается.

Comment: Намучаетесь вы с этим API :) Бэкенд игнорирует ваш параметр `auto=4`, когда генерит ссылку на следующую страницу. Соответственно, запросив ее, вы получите неверную страницу данных. Посылайте им bug report :)